# Organisation have restrictions on Db access, how to proceed with development

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, mocking

I am working as a vendor for an organisation and due to some sensitive data restrictions i cannot be provided with the database access (we are using postgres) but still expected to develop with the same pace as the employees with access.

It is a NodeJs application and hence i came across Sinon js through which i can mock the database calls in my testcases following the TDD process for my development.
This works fine but consumes a lot of time which my organisation is not fine with.

I am looking forward to get thoughts on this from all the experience folks who can guide me if i am on a right track by following the TDD process or is there any other way where I can just mock the complete database in my local system for my development purpose.

Comment: If you have access to this DB from one of your lab server, you can create a tunnel using that lab server. I usually tunnel things otherwise not accessible directly but are accessible from lab(e.g. QA or UAT env)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a copy of the database where all sensitive data are masked. There are tools out there that can help you with that. Then you have a database to work with, which is required for developing an application that uses a database.

Yes, data masking is cumbersome, and the onus will fall on your customer, which won't make them happy. But they have to make that investment if they want you to be productive. Failure to do so will make them waste even more money (on you).